# Azure Databricks Python multiprocessing API calls with the requests library?

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, databricks

We're currently trying to figure out a way to pull a large amount of data from a API endpoint via Azure Databricks. We were hoping the multiprocessing would work for the Python we already had written with a little refactoring on the Databricks platform but it doesn't seem that it actually supports the Python 3 multiprocessing libraries so there isn't much to be gained running our code on this platform. Are we correct in assuming we need to pivot to Pyspark or just scala for this task or are there better alternatives we should be looking at?

Comment: Why do you need multiprocessing?  Are you sharing data between processes?

Comment: We are trying to split up the call to be handled quicker, so probably better stated as worker processes.

Comment: could you use a [`SocketTextStream`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.StreamingContext.socketTextStream) in `pyspark` to address this? Seems to support streaming content from a `url`, not sure if that would support an API as well...

Comment: I'd look at something like azure data factory or azure functions to get the data. Use databricks to process it once it have all been downloaded.

Comment: @simon_dmorias Thanks for the suggestion, I think that is what we were going to pivot over to. The data factory REST support is better but still not great so probably just going to write it as a Azure Function. I think they have execution time limits so going to have to play around with the code to break it up or scale it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I known, there is a service named [`Azure Batch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-technical-overview) on Azure which is very suitable for your current scenario to pull a large amount of data from an API endpoint in parallel and can be scale up.

You can refer to the offical tutorials [`Quickstart: Run your first Batch job with the Python API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-python) and [`Quickstart: Upload, download, and list blobs with Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) to know how to use it in Python and integrate with Azure Storage SDK for Python to download the data to Blob Storage. Then you can connect to Blob Storage as data source in Azure Databricks for doing the follow-up data processing, please refer to the offical document [`Connect to data sources from Azure Databricks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-connect-to-data-sources) and the Azure databricks topic [`Azure Blob Storage`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) to know it.

If you have any concern, please feel free to let me know.